# What is the torque and sequence for a '99 Jetta Oil Pan?

Tags: torque, tdi, oil-pan

I have a '99 Jetta TDI (diesel) with a cracked oil pan.  I'm looking for the sequence of tightening the bolts and the torque needed for each bolt.  I've been doing to google-fu but can't seem to find it. Does anyone specifically know these details, or where I can maybe find this?

*Note: Can someone with priv please put 'oil-pan' and 'bolt-sequence' as tags :)*

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a workshop manual for the car? The torque figures should be listed in there. In the UK Haynes manuals they are at the beginning of the relevant chapter.

I'm not aware of a specific order for oil sump bolts, but if there is one it should be listed in the approprate section of said manual. Normally it is only head bolts that need to be tightened in a certain sequence, but I don't know about modern VW engines.

Answer (score 0):

Oil pans don't have a specific bolt sequence like a cylinder head or crankshaft bolts.

This link should be helpful: [TDIClub Forums - View Single Post -  frequently asked torque specs](http://65.110.12.166/showpost.php?s=c011f9b152f23c487d74809065f29ae5&p=2785519&postcount=59):

> Use Silicone sealant D 176 404 A2
>
> **Removing**
>   Remove center, left and right sound insulation trays:
>
> Drain engine oil.
>
> Remove securing bolts for oil pan.
>
> Loosen oil pan with light blows of a rubber-headed hammer, if necessary.
>
> Remove oil pan.
>
> Remove sealant residue on cylinder block with a flat scraper.
>
> Remove sealant residue on oil pan with a rotating brush, e.g. a drill motor with a plastic brush (wear eye protection).
>
> Clean sealing surfaces. Surfaces must be free of oil and grease.
>
> **Installing**
>   Note: Observe the use-by date of the sealing compound.
>
> The oil pan must be installed within 5 minutes of applying the silicone sealing compound.
>
> Cut off tube nozzle at forward marking (approx. nozzle diameter: 3 mm).
>
> Apply silicone sealing compound, as shown, to clean oil pan sealing surface. Sealant bead must be 2 to 3 mm thick
>
> Run along inner side of bolt holes
>
> The sealing compound bead must not be thicker, otherwise excess sealing compound will enter the oil pan and may block the oil suction pipe strainer.
>
> Apply silicone sealant bead carefully as shown to areas marked by arrows. (Illustration shows position of sealant bead on cylinder block).
>
> Install oil pan immediately and tighten all oil pan bolts lightly.
>
> The oil pan must be flush with the cylinder block.
>
> **Tighten oil pan bolts to 15 Nm.**
>
> Tighten oil pan/transmission bolts to 45 Nm.
>
> Let the sealing compound dry for approx. 30 minutes after installing the oil pan. Only then fill the engine with oil.
>
> Further assembly is basically the reverse of the disassembly procedure.

Comment: When posting a link copy paste and or summarize the content so in the event the information is moved or deleted it will still be here

Comment: My 2009 Sentra service manual does recommend a bolt instalation sequence.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Bentley manual (ISBN 0-8376-0366-8), page 17-1, tighten the oil pan bolts to 20 Nm (15 ft*lb), and the drain plug to 30 Nm (22 ft*lb).

And as others have mentioned, there is no specific prescribed sequence.